# Generic Response of a WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, generic-programming

I just wrote a C# Lib to handle WebRequests safely (Which can be found, with the code open , [Here](http://pastebin.com/2viG0cNL))

At the moment, my GET Method will always return a string as the response, but sometimes like when fetching captchas from a site, it will need to return a Bitmap instead.

How do i do This ? How do i use a sort of  Type to make this Get request as generic as possible, making possible for anyone to choose the type of response it will receive.

**Improving Question:**

This is what i tried now. It does not compiles because it says it can't convert a `String` to a Type `T` on this line :

```
response = (T) new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

This is my new Method :

```
public T Get <T> (string url)
    {
        T response = default(T);

        // Checking for empty url
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            throw new Exception("URL para o Request não foi configurada ou é nula.");
        }

        try
        {
            // Re-Creating Request Object to avoid exceptions
            m_HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create (url) as HttpWebRequest;

            m_HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer              = m_CookieJar;
            m_HttpWebRequest.Method                       = "GET";
            m_HttpWebRequest.UserAgent                    = m_userAgent;
            m_HttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = m_connectionsLimit;
            m_HttpWebRequest.Timeout                      = m_timeout;
            m_HttpWebRequest.ContentType                  = m_contentType;
            m_HttpWebRequest.Referer                      = m_referer;
            m_HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect            = m_allowAutoRedirect;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_host))
            {
                m_HttpWebRequest.Host = m_host;
            }

            // Execute web request and wait for response
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse) m_HttpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
              response = (T) new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            m_error  = ex.ToString();

            if (m_logOnError)
                LogWriter.Error(ex);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Thats out pattern for naming class attributes. Also, trolling me won't help me

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:**

You could encode the bitmap using Base64. Here's an example that shows you how: http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx

This way, you always return a string, even when you return an image :-)

**Approach 2:**

You could append type info to the URL, like so:

```
GET /mypage/whatever/api?x=3&y=4&t=image
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what i want to actually.
I am looking for a way to make this GET method as generic as possible, allowing the user to "choose" the return type of the method, getting the desired response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics, or you can just pass the `Type` of the object you want.

```
   private T Get<T>()
    {
        Type t_type = typeof(T);

        if (t_type == typeof(string))
        {
            // return string
        }
        else if (t_type == typeof(Bitmap))
        {
            // return bitmap
        }
    }
```

Then call it like so.

```
Bitmap b = response.Get<Bitmap>();
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it without the "ifs" ?
Like instantiating one response object based on the type T received and using it as a return ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would say yes if you were only returning primitive types.  But when it gets more complex, such as `Bitmap`s... I don't know.

Comment: Let me know if you figure out how... Something like : T response = new T();

Comment: Well you can create `T`.  `T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`.  The problem is creating it from the response stream.  Not all objects are constructed equally.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you are most of the way there. If the response happens to be a bitmap, it's how you display or interpret that data that matters.

At the end of the day, what you have is a set of bytes which comprises the string you return from your get method, regardless of whether that content is a string or an image.

You could (for example, code not tested) convert this string back to bytes, and then to a bitmap.

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(responseString);

TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap) tc.ConvertFrom(bytes);
```

When displaying data to a user, if in a web browser, the interpretation of what the browser should do with the response can be controlled by the response headers:

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=Report.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

Comment: Is there any way i can convert a String into a `Type T` ?

Comment: I've Found out how : http://predicatet.blogspot.com/2009/04/c-string-to-generic-type-conversion.html